# find selected item text or position in check-boxes inside the gridview

Tags: java, android

I want to find checked item text or position in checkboxes which is 
casted inside gridView (android:choiceMode="multipleChoice")

```
my_Adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
         my_array);
 gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.part_list);
 gridView.setAdapter(my_Adapter2);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple ListView Multiple choice Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630562/simple-listview-multiple-choice-android)

Comment: DUDE .I want to use gridview also I am using checkbox in multiplechoice mode of gridview so I want selected item not clicked item