# Dynamically change text color of some ListView element

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to dynamically change the color of the text shown inside a ListView. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460407/change-text-color-for-listview-items) discussion but it's not what I'm looking for. I will explain my situation. Upon `onCreate`, my app calla an asynctask that builds a ListView with some string downloaded from a server. Then checks if inside a custom folder there exists a file with a name equal to one of those strings. If yes, I would like to change the color of the text corresponding to the existing file. How can i do that?

Comment: I don't know why you can't do that when you check if the folder exist.

Comment: Are you using custom list adapter??????

Comment: You have to create a list that contains all your row data (and if folder is present or not). Pass it to you customer adapter, and then change your text color depending of your data

Comment: no, i'm not using a custom adapter, but a defeult ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @azerto00 ok i've understand what you say, but in that way, if for some reason after list is created with correct color, a new file is added to folder, i don't want clear ListView and build it again

Comment: Yes in this case, you have to do something else. 
This means that you have to be aware of folder changes/creation when it happens

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom list adapter, for example you can extend `BaseAdapter` for that purpose. Then you should define something like `model` of your list data item and when `model` changed, you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and `BaseAdapter.getView()` should draw changed views as you want: with different colors or something else.

You would better read some articles about `ListView` and `Adapters`, like [Vogella's Android ListView - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Or you can ask me here if you don't understand something :)