# Change text color and padding from Android ListView in ArrayList XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview

I searched for this in stackoverflow and in google, but I didn't found.
My API version is 8 (Android 2.3) and I don't want to change it to lastest.

I have ListView in Array:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#151515"
    android:cacheColorHint="#151515"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menuid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:divider="#151515"
        android:color="#ffffff"
        android:entries="@array/menu_array" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and Array in strings.xml:

```
<string-array translatable="false" name="menu_array">
    <item>News</item>
    <item>Live</item>
    <item>About me</item>
    <item>FAQ</item>
    <item>Settings</item>
    <item>Informations</item>
</string-array>
```

I cannot change to ListAdapter.
And my question is how to change text color of item, add icon to items?

Comment: kindle go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460407/change-text-color-for-listview-items?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460407/change-text-color-for-listview-items?rq=1)

Comment: No, it's not this, I don't use TextView and ListView, only ListView.

Comment: default ArrayAdapter not provide this kind of modification so you have make custom Adapter for your requirement...

Comment: then there no way to achieve this. You should implement custom adapter for this. thnx

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>  adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.countries, R.layout.spinner_layout);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

spinner_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drop_bg"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```